# how to customize the JSON serialized name in MVC4 Web API?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I have searched web for my question without success, so I post question here.

I am using MVC4 Web API for providing JSON data to client. Because C# uses Pascal naming convention, so by default the client received JSON data are also in Pascal naming convention, how do I customize this to return camel naming convention in JSON?

another issue is how to change the serialized name? for example, in C# I have a property named "Description", but in order to reduce the data size, I would like to serialize it as "descr" in JSON, how to achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I know this is an old post, but I thought it was worth adding a reference to Json.Net:

[API Reference](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.aspx)

[Nuget Page](http://www.nuget.org/packages/NewtonSoft.Json/)

You can set the name that each property will serialize **to and from** using the `JsonProperty` attribute:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [JsonProperty("myJsonProp")]
    public string MyJsonProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
//Serialize
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(instanceOfMyModel);

//De-serialize
var deserialized = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeSerializeOject<MyModel>(json);
```

The resulting Json:

```
"{
    "myJsonProp" : "value"
}"
```

Comment: Hi Oliver, you answer is never late, and I find this is a very grace solution. I never though there is such a attribute before you answer me! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The post http://blog.alexonasp.net/post/2012/04/05/Lowercase-JSON-with-ASPNET-Web-API.aspx exactly answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution, but in a similar situation I've just returned a json formatted string which is in the format that I want instead of using the automatic serialization.  You might be able to find other serialization libraries out there that allow you to do what you want.

Comment: I hoped there is an attribute to be put on each property of my model object to declare the formatted name.